# glDeleteBuffers slower than glBufferData

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I'm having a bit of performance issue in my iOS/Android game where several VBO's have to be updated every once in a while. After profiling my game it turns out that glDeleteBuffers() takes up to 7ms per VBO update. This of course results in a hiccup when frames normally take only 4 ms to render.

Here's the part where I update my VBO:

```
Chunk* chunk;
pthread_join(constructionThread, (void**)&chunk);
building = false;

if (vboID)
{
    //takes 7 milliseconds
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboID); 
    vboID = 0;
}
if (offset)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

    //takes about 1-2 milliseconds, which is acceptable
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset * 4, constructionBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

where offset is an instance variable is basically the size of the new VBO, which is quite variable. vboID speaks for itself, I guess ;)

Comment: Why delete them if you're just going to recreate them?

Comment: because they were going to be different size anyway. I thought of them as regular arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glGenBuffers` and `glDeleteBuffers` are designed to only be run on initialization and cleanup, respectively. Calling them during runtime is bad.

`glBufferData` replaces the current buffer data with a new set of data, which automatically changes the size of the buffer. You can safely remove the whole `glGenBuffers`/`glDeleteBuffers` thing and move it into initialization and cleanup.

Additionally, you are creating the buffer as a static buffer. This is telling OpenGL that you will almost never change it so it stores it in a way that's quicker to access on the GPU but slower to access from the rest of the system. Try changing `GL_STATIC_DRAW` to `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` or `GL_STREAM_DRAW`. More on this here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Objects#Buffer_Object_Usage

Comment: GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW is used when the buffer content are generated on GPU, and used for drawing: this doesn't seem the case of the question.

Comment: He mentioned that `glBufferData` took 1-2ms, changing the usage hint can speed it up quite a bit. And the `COPY` hint is used for GPU-generated data that the user never directly reads from.

Comment: @Luca: The STATIC/DYNAMIC/STREAM is about the *frequency* of changes, not where the content comes from.

Comment: @Nicolas: you're right, as usual. I got a lapsus now, but luckily my personal abstraction layer implemented some year ago is correct... Not too bad.