# Multiple, dynamic model data in opengl

Tags: opengl

So i've been doing a little OpenGL. Version 3.3. Its been going great. However, there is one question I cannot think of an answer to: How would one support a system where there are an undefined amount of models with undefined data. An example of what I mean is, say there is a model, and you want to chop it in half. There would be two new objects created, one for each half of the model. Creating the new objects is trivial (generating the cut mesh is a little harder).

What I do not consider trivial, because I don't know how to do it, is sending the new mesh data to OpenGL. It is not possible to just update the VBO of the original object, because there now needs to be TWO VBOs. It would be possible, and easy, with glGenBuffers(), to just generate buffers on the fly. However, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10769008/2159051, it is mentioned that genBuffers, deleteBuffers are horrible to call during runtime.

In short, what is the correct way to do dynamic amounts of objects, each with separate data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to call glGenBuffers, glDeleteBuffers and glBufferData during runtime. The only trouble is, if they're called for each and every frame. If you happen to perform only the occasional data update they're perfectly fine to use.

Comment: Perfect. The data won't be every frame, just every once in a while. In addition, I now see the answer i referred to was in the context of a mobile OpenGL environment, so that would explain his explanation.

Comment: @BWG: It doesn't matter if mobile or desktop. That linked answer is simply inaccurate in that regard. If you have changed data, you have changed data. No way around this. However what you can do (and if your system reaches a certain complexity you should do it), is using VBO not as a mesh store for individual "objects", but as memory pools from which you allocate smaller slices. You can always change the data with little cost using glBufferSubData if the first glBufferData call was done with a usage hint that indicates the access pattern.

Comment: That's interesting! So you are saying i should use some sort of manual memory management system? And when rendering (i use drawArrays for the time being) just render part of the VBO? If that is what you are saying, the concept is quite appealing!

Comment: @BWG: Yes, that's the general idea. Of course the details of the actual implementation depend on the task at hand. Just remember that a `glDraw…` call can only work with the buffer objects bound at the time of the calling (this might change in the future; something similar to bindless textures may come along).

Comment: Yeah... i figured that. Thanks for the help! This is one of the few cases where I understand the execution, but not the concept. Usually, its the opposite.