# glDeleteBuffers CPU usage on iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl-es

I am working a mobile rendering library using C++ and GLES 2. In my sample project, which is a basic demostration app (for both android and iOS), I render a map. Because of the movement, zoom etc. of the map, geometry has to change dramatically. This has to happen as quickly as possible.

**The library is using shared GL contexts**. The main draws directly to the screen some simple textured quads. The other one is bound to background worker thread and is drawing complicated geometry to those textures. It also handles all of the mesh deletion operations.

The *Mesh* class contains VBO and IBO buffers. It has logic for drawing. When the mesh is to be thrown away, there are two calls to glDeleteBuffers to delete both vbo and ibo buffers.

```
void Mesh::free()
{
    if (vbo_ != 0)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo_);
    if (ibo_ != 0)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibo_);
}
```

**My problem is only happening on iOS, the CPU spends very long time on these two calls.** CPU usage goes to 100% and I can watch memory usage very slowly go down. I can't tell what could be the cause for that. **The same scene is smooth on Android**, I don't have to wait couple seconds. This is a huge problem for me, since the library aims to achieve at least 30 fps on average phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [glDeleteBuffers slower than glBufferData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768929/gldeletebuffers-slower-than-glbufferdata)

Comment: I saw that question, but it didn't really help me. I already tried GL_STREAM_DRAW with no apparent difference. Imagine a map library, you can't pregenerate the buffers on start, because you load parts of the map dynamically. I also tried very simple pooling method, but I am not sure using glBufferData on existing vbo is really safe?
Also why would this only be a problem on iOS, difference in OpenGL implementation I maybe?

Comment: Could you try deferring the deletion for a couple of frames after you last use them? Maybe it's slow because the driver is waiting for the GPU to finish with those resources.