# Why are glDeleteBuffers and glDeleteVertexArrays so slow?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, vbo, vao

At some point in my program's flow I generate anywhere from between 0 and 300 meshes, each of them like so:

```
public Mesh(float[] vertices, byte[] indices, float[] textureCoordinates)
{
    vao = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    vbo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ShaderProgram.VERTEX_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ShaderProgram.VERTEX_ATTRIB);

    tbo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(textureCoordinates), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ShaderProgram.TCOORD_ATTRIB, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ShaderProgram.TCOORD_ATTRIB);

    ibo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

When the user presses a button these meshes need to be deleted again, so I run a cleanup method on each of these mesh objects:

```
public void cleanup()
{
        glDeleteBuffers(vbo);
        glDeleteBuffers(tbo);
        glDeleteBuffers(ibo);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);
}
```

The problem is that I am trying to run at 60 fps and deleting 70 of these mesh objects takes about 30 ms (and deleting 110 of them takes 75 ms). This creates a noticable hiccup in performance because one frame should take at most ~16 ms.

Is this not the right way to dispose of VBO's and VAO's? I read in a different question ([glDeleteBuffers slower than glBufferData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768929/gldeletebuffers-slower-than-glbufferdata)) that

> glGenBuffers and glDeleteBuffers are designed to only be run on initialization and cleanup, respectively. Calling them during runtime is bad.

but I am not sure how I can get rid of these VBO's and VAO's without calling the above functions.

I have thought of adding all meshes-to-be-deleted to a queue and only deleting a couple of them each frame, slowly emptying the queue, but that does not feel like the right solution. Another (possible) solution I have thought of is to use instanced rendering, but, as far as I understand, when I make sub 1000 draw calls per frame, non-instanced rendering should work fine too. My program will never have much more than 1000 Mesh objects at any given time, and I am not even sure this will solve my problem.

UPDATE: Besides from the below answer pointing me in exactly the right direction, I also discovered I wasn't actually deleting ~0-300 VBO's, but a factor of *48* more! No wonder performance was killed. So if anyone else ever has the same problem, thoroughly check the amount of glDeleteBuffers your code is performing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hit some mental roadblock there. You seem to think that *"per mesn: {one vertex attribute == one VBO}"*, but that's not how its supposed to work. What you should do is use one single, large VBO and use as a pool of memory from which you allocate chunks, each holding some data.

So you put not only all the vertex attributes of a single mesh into a common VBO, you also put several meshes into a single VBO.

Also it seems like you're creating and deleting your VBOs and VAOs on every single rendering iteration. Why? Do the meshes dramatically change between every frame? If that is so, that must be epilepsy inducing to watch; mesh deformations baked into the geometry data don't require recreation of the buffers, you just overwrite the data with `glBufferSubData`.

Comment: I only create and delete each VBO/VAO once. Each frame the render method on each Mesh object gets called, which contains this: `glBindVertexArray(vao);  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);  glBindVertexArray(0);`  The position of each mesh gets passed to the shader, I don't recreate a Mesh object for that.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that the vertex buffer, the texture coordinates buffer and the index buffer can all be stored in one VBO? And with "you also put several meshes into a single VBO." you mean instanced rendering?

Comment: @Thorakh: Placing several meshes into a single buffer is something entirely different than instanced rendering. With instanced rendering you're the *same* data in multiple instanced (with different transformation applied) using a single draw call. But having several meshes in one buffer can draw them either by supplying a longer index buffer and fewer draw calls, or by multiple draw calls.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I'll look into doing that. If I have less VBO's, deleting them will take less time as well I suppose, even if each individual VBO is bigger. But glDeleteBuffers is supposed to be slow then?